# CellStyle dataformat for XLSX

Tags: java, apache-poi, export-to-excel, xssf, poi-hssf

I have some code like :

```
CellStyle cs2 = wb.createCellStyle();
CellStyle cs4 = wb.createCellStyle();
cs4.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC"));
cs2.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("text"));
```

this is for creating xls reports. How do i change this code to create XLSX reports ?

will the following work ?

```
XSSFDataFormat format = (XSSFDataFormat) wb.createDataFormat();

            cs2.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("text"));
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, built-in formats will still work with .xlsx spreadsheets in Apache POI.

Even if the Javadocs for [`XSSFDataFormat#getFormat(String)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDataFormat.html#getFormat(java.lang.String)) don't mention it, the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.9/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDataFormat.java#XSSFDataFormat.getFormat%28java.lang.String%29) tells all:

```
public short getFormat(String format) {
    int idx = BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(format);
    if(idx == -1) idx = stylesSource.putNumberFormat(format);
    return (short)idx;
}
```

It will look up the data format in the `BuiltinFormats` object first, and if not found, it will create a new one.

I've tested this on creating a .xlsx spreadsheet, and using `"text"` works.  I created numeric cells, and I set those cells to a `CellStyle` with a `XSSFDataFormat` created with `"text"`, and the cells are "text"-styled in the resultant spreadsheet.